# Resize a bitmap as big that the screen can in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, image, android-imageview

I'm using methods to edit the dimensions of a picture but I can't size it to take the entiere screen... I already try to put "FILL_PARENT" as an argument but it doesn't work!

Here's my code fragment that's working :

```
ImageView image; 
Bitmap bitmap;
...
image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 300, 300, false));
```

I already found a solution but we have to use Canvas and I feel that there is a simplest way! (for information : ["The canvas way"](http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html) )

I have a problem with the gestures too. To be able to capt gestures, I have to "play" with views :

```
GestureOverlayView v = (GestureOverlayView)findViewById(R.id.gestures);
    v.removeAllViews();
    v.addView(image, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Thanks to help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code to get the width and height of your device.

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = display.getWidth();
        int height = display.getHeight();
```

And now set the bitmap width and height based on the value returned by the above methods.

Comment: THANK YOU for your help, but there are vaguenesses : http://www.imagup.com/data/1122798288.html

Comment: is your image of lesser width than you have provided it with?

Comment: @Androi_selva : ok, it's better with wider pictures but the swipe isn't running; I make a GestureOverlayView (that will contain the imageview), and I can't add the imageview (check the initial post)